# How to make an API call vi groovy

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

i have this python scriptt that allows me to to make an api call to a url very easily . if i try the same thing with groovy it is not working .. Tried many things but still failing .

I am very noob in groovy but i need an alternative to below python api call which can be easily called from jenkins pipeline

```
token = 'xxxx-yyy-zzz-aaa'
headers = {'Authorization': "some-name%s" % token}
tar_endpoint = 'https://abc@hello.com'

r = requests.post(tar_endpoint, data=json.dumps(som_json_payload), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet below should do the job for you

```
def post = new URL("url_goes_here").openConnection();
def message = '{"message":"this is the data we want to post"}'
post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
// add more headers if needed
post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if(postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

Comment: exactly the answer i needed ... Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Have you eliminated using any of the plugins that might support this?

- [HTTP Post](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http-post/)
- [HTTP Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/)
- [Pipeline: Groovy HTTP](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-cps-http/)
- [Pipeline: REST API](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-rest-api/)
- [REST List Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rest-list-parameter/)

That's the thing w/Jenkins, most of the time, "[there's a plugin fot that](https://plugins.jenkins.io/)", you just need to be able to find it.